# Can Android Studio do Code Alignment?

Tags: android, formatting, android-studio

I'd like to align my source code to make it look neater. It improves readability. For example:

```
    dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
    mTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
```

I'd like to reformat it to this:

```
    dataList      = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
    mTitle        = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList   = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
```

And this:

```
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Message", R.drawable.ic_action_email));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Likes", R.drawable.ic_action_good));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Games", R.drawable.ic_action_gamepad));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Lables", R.drawable.ic_action_labels));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Search", R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Cloud", R.drawable.ic_action_cloud));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Camara", R.drawable.ic_action_camera));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Video", R.drawable.ic_action_video));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Groups", R.drawable.ic_action_group));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Import & Export", R.drawable.ic_action_import_export));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("About", R.drawable.ic_action_about));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.drawable.ic_action_settings));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Help", R.drawable.ic_action_help));
```

to this:

```
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Message",         R.drawable.ic_action_email));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Likes",           R.drawable.ic_action_good));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Games",           R.drawable.ic_action_gamepad));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Lables",          R.drawable.ic_action_labels));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Search",          R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Cloud",           R.drawable.ic_action_cloud));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Camara",          R.drawable.ic_action_camera));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Video",           R.drawable.ic_action_video));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Groups",          R.drawable.ic_action_group));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Import & Export", R.drawable.ic_action_import_export));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("About",           R.drawable.ic_action_about));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings",        R.drawable.ic_action_settings));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Help",            R.drawable.ic_action_help));
```

Very useful, this:

```
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
```

to this:

```
    private DrawerLayout          mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView              mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence          mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence          mTitle;
```

Any advice on how I can do this?

Comment: As a side note - I know this doesn't answer the question as such - this "prettified" code is sort of an antipattern, difficult to maintain, and nothing else but putting lipstick on a pig if the code suffers from actual readability problems (and if it doesn't, why bother at all?). Reputed books about best practice typically advice against doing this, eg. "Clean code" by Robert C. Martin (see Formatting / Horizontal alignment).

Comment: Eh. It was trivial and took no time at all in Vim, and there was an incredible speed benefit when reading the code later. Unfortunately, the lack of integration of Vim with everything else needed to do Android makes it overall more difficult nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

As much as I agree with @KonradMorawski (just don't do it, although it's sometimes tempting), this can be done in Android Studio (or IntelliJ). Go to Preferences > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Field Groups, and check "Align in columns".

[image: Example screenshot]